# Can someone help me stop an arc4random generated number from appearing again?

Tags: swift, if-statement, arc4random

Im using `arc4random` to generate a random number which im then using to display an image asset but i need a button that will stop `arc4random` generating that number again once its pressed

```
 @IBAction func Button(_ sender: Any) {


        let BugRandom = arc4random_uniform(18)


        Smallbug.image = UIImage(named: "Bug\(BugRandom)")


    }
```

Does anyone know if this is possible or what i should be looking for?

Comment: Did you check [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+random+without+repetition)?

Comment: I did not, looks like theres everything i need in there. Sorry, first time using this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var randomAssets: Set<Int> = Set(0...18)

@IBAction func Button(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let random = randomAssets.randomElement() else {
        return
    }
    randomAssets.remove(random)
    Smallbug.image = UIImage(named: "Bug\(random)")
}
```

But there is a warning, after 18 times it stop working obviously.